# Visual Basic Drag and Drop Window

Tags: file, vbscript, drag-and-drop, directory

I have found this code which allows me to drag and drop files onto to script icon and put them in a specified directory:

```
Const MyDestinationFolder = "C:\Temp\" 
Const OverwriteExisting = True 

Dim objFile,objFolder 
Dim Arg 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then 
    For Each Arg in Wscript.Arguments 
        Arg =  Trim(Arg) 
    If InStr(Arg,".") Then 
    ' Assume a File 
      Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(Arg) 
      ' Copy file to the Dest Folder using the same name 
      objFile.Copy MyDestinationFolder & objFile.Name,OverwriteExisting 
    Else 
    'Assume a Folder 
      Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Arg) 
      ' Copy Folder to the Dest Folder 
      objFolder.Copy MyDestinationFolder, OverwriteExisting 
    End If 
    Next 
End If
```

However I would like to make a script that runs and has a simple rectangle that says, drag and drop here. If this is at all possible, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible with just WSH/VBScript. VBScript has no GUI features. Other than MsgBox and InputBox, it has no windows at all, and neither of those can be used as drop targets. Windows, not VBScript, is responsible for the drag-and-drop operation you're experiencing on your script icon. You'd almost certainly have to use an HTA but I'm not sure if that will work, either. IFrames are drop targets but I doubt VBScript could receive their events.

Comment: Okay, is there any launguage that comes installed with windows that will work for my purpose?

Comment: take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DragDrop(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a GUI to VBScript programs by using "HTML Applications (HTAs)". Start your research here:

- [Introduction to HTML Applications (HTAs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Extreme Makeover: Wrap Your Scripts Up in a GUI Interface](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx)
- [A Scriptomatic You Can Call Your Own](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692617.aspx)
- [HTML Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application)
- [HTML Applications (HTAs)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692926.aspx)
- [Scripting Eye for the GUI Guy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332541.aspx)

and - of course

- [stackoverflow questions tagged hta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hta)

**After** second thoughts on "Drag & Drop", I found:

- [this claim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/753606/603855) and [that .HTA](http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/www/wsh/imager/index.html) (not tested)